# Does the trait "Magical Knack" affect familiars?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

With 2 or more levels in a different class and then 1 lvl in a familiar granting class (such as Witch) and the magical [Knack trait](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-knack)  (up to +2 trait bonus to CL) make the [familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar) abilities/level 3 (thus +1 INT, +1 Natural Armor, +1 "Special")?

> All familiars have special abilities (or impart abilities to their masters) depending on the *master's combined level in classes that grant familiars*, as shown on the table below. The abilities are cumulative.

I assume that means no, but since a trait is half a feat and the feet boon actually boosts it up to +4 in a similar fashion it might be intended to work. What do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Caster levels bonuses are different than actual levels in a class.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Caster-Level

Comment: +1 and this might impact your understanding of Magical Knack and your other questions - upped caster level does not give you more spells or *anything* other than an upped level-variable duration/range/effect for the spells you can cast. It is less than "+1 spellcaster level".

Comment: I did get that it doesn't give me any more spells, which is why I'm having such a hard time choosing between sorcerer and witch, as the witch can apply this bonus to a ton of different spells (if he ever has them prepared :-S ), while the sorcerer could apply this to spells he uses every day all the time.

For crafting items the increased CL would still count though, as right?